# Why can't I use setUnlocalizedName(String) return undefined when I use ItemSpatialMark

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

```
package itsjustlogic.logicmod;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

@Mod(modid = "logic", name = "Logic's Mod", version = "1.0")
public class LogicsMod {
    
    public static Item itemSpatialMark;
    
    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        //Item/Block init and reg
        //Config handling
        itemSpatialMark = new ItemSpatialMark().setUnlocalizedName("ItemSpatialMark");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(itemSpatialMark, itemSpatialMark.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event){
        //Proxy, TileEntity, entity, GUI, and Packet Reg
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event){
        
    }
}
```

Error: The method setUnlocalizedName(String) is undefined for the type ItemSpatialMark

I know this is kinda a basic question and theres probably a simple fix but I'm new to coding with forge. please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ItemSpacialMark` class, make sure that you're extending the `net.minecraft.item.Item` class like this,

```java
 public class ItemSpacialMark extends Item { // Your code here }
```

And, it is preferred to assign the name in `setUnlocalizedName(String name)` method through passing the arguments to the constructor like this,

```java
public ItemSpacialMark(String unlocalizedName){
       setRegistryName("reg-name");
       setUnlocalizedName(unlocalizedName);
}
```

And, while calling the constructor,

```java
itemSpacialMark = new ItemSpacialMark("some name");
```